# How to create a dynamic horizontal scrolling using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I want to create a slide view for our products but I don't want to load all of them at once. I want to buffer 1 page ahead and before and when the user clicks next shift everything to right and remove the second DIV from previous pages like FIFO. so I always need to have 3 DIVs inside the #content class PREVIOUS, CURRENT and NEXT. something like [this website](http://designarchives.aiga.org/#/entries/+collections%3a%22AIGA%20365%3a%20Design%20Effectiveness%20%282011%29%22/_/slideshow/relevance/asc/0/7/0/title/1) ! any help is really appreciated. I did everything else but this part is taking too long :(

Comment: What approach have you tried thus far?

Comment: I was trying to get it to work using a jQuery plugin called jQuery.ScrollTo and load the content with AJAX but no luck. I'm using PHP with MVC arch on the server, I have a search class that accepts a json object and returns the results. for each view (i'm working on slider view right now) i pass the search parameter, the selected view and the page product limit(for pagination purpose) to the class and it returns the content for that page.

Comment: Try adding your code to the question...that will give people something to work with.

Comment: You could implement that relatively easy by using some AJAX calls in JQuery. You just load the "new" parts asynchronously from a .php page for instance, passing on some parameters such as `item_from=1&item_to=5`. So make like a long list of items, only showing the center (use CSS). If a user slides, remove some of the items which is moving the center view, and append the new items that are loaded through AJAX. Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a sample for you try it @ http://jsfiddle.net/rifat/xzxPQ/

Hope it'll help :)